# How to detect the last cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

This table view delegate code to detect the last table cell doesn't work.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        if (indexPath.row == self.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: 0) - 1) {
            ...
        }
   }
```

The "last row" as determined by the code moves up and down the list as I scroll. How do I fix this?

Comment: Moves up and down? Do you mean you want the last visible cell?

Comment: It means that you either have few sections instead of one or (more likely) you don't handle `else` case and you previous last cell is reused.

Comment: No, the cell that corresponds to element at the end of the data source. "Last visible cell", sounds like what its currently doing.

Comment: Sounds odd. Is your datasource is changing while you scroll up and down?

Comment: @Ossie Your second solution is correct.

Comment: @shim Otherwise I get the parameter called "tableView".

Comment: @Ossie Actually, its still not working even when there's an else condition.

Comment: @Ossie It was part of the solution. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the number of the sections for the tableView is more than 1,so you need to take the section into calculation(you should make sure that `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRows` is greater than 0):

```
let numberOfSections = self.tableView.numberOfSections

let numberOfRows = self.tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(numberOfSections-1)

if indexPath.row == numberOfRows - 1 && indexPath.section == numberOfSections - 1{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
if (indexPath == [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(numberOfRowsInLastSection - 1) inSection:(numberOfSections - 1)])
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, your last section might be empty, so you want to look for the section last section which contains a cell. This can be done by looping over each section, and in each section loop over each cell. While doing this, keep track of the last indexPath of the cell you encountered, and when the loop is done, you can retrieve the last cell using the indexPath.

Something like this should work:

```
NSIndexPath *lastCellIndexPath;
for (NSInteger sectionIndex = self.tableView.numberOfSections - 1; sectionIndex >= 0; sectionIndex--) {
    if ([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:sectionIndex] > 0) {
        NSInteger section = sectionIndex;
        NSInteger row = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:sectionIndex] - 1;
        lastCellIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
        break;
    }
}

// Retrieve your cell with the indexPath
...
```

Comment: I already have the cell as a result of "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier".

Answer (score 0):

My cell contains a UIView that draws inside `drawRect` and the output is different for the starting and ending table cells. I've found that if I do the following...

```
cell!.contLine.setNeedsDisplay()
```

...then the drawing is correct. (`contLine` is the embedded UIView). If I call `setNeedsDisplay` on the cell then it doesn't work. So I'm having to break encapsulation here.

As a result of Ossie's suggestion, I've also changed the detection code so that it updates the state of the cell every time. Otherwise, a reused cell's state can be stale.

```
cell!.isEnd = (indexPath.row == (self.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: 0) - 1))
```